# Unable to parse Dynatrace Instrumented APK file

Tags: android, instrumentation, jarsigner, zipalign, dynatrace

I used the Dynatrace auto-instrumentor command on my Android apk file

```
auto-instrumentor.cmd apk <apk file> prop <APK-Instr.properties>
```

and then signed it with my keystore.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore mykeystore.keystore myApp.apk aliasname
```

Finally I zip align it using the below command:

```
zipalign -f -v 4 AppFile.apk AppFile2.apk
```

But when I try to install the file, I get a parsing error:

> There is a problem parsing the package.

**Note**: I have been able to successfully verify the jar using the below command:

```
jarsigner -verify -keystore mystore.keystore AppFile.apk
```

But still get the parsing error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using changing the hash algorithms and retrying. You may use either SHA2 or SHA256 as a start.

Note that SHA1 is being deprecated  by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your APK was signed with a debug key when it was first built.  Running jarsigner again could be signing it a second time.

Take a look at [this question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224091/install-parse-failed-no-certificates-failure-installing-modified-apk-file-inval/23228801#23228801) here to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, my scenario is different.